# Deployment is successful but app is not running on emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using VS 2019 and Android SDK API 30.

The deployment of the android app is successful message is shown in the output window but the app is not seen on the emulator.

[image]

The output log is posted below:
**Output Log:**

```
            Build started...
            1>------ Build started: Project: Jeevitham, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
            ...
            4>Starting deployment to pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 ...
            4>Starting emulator pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 ...
            4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -verbose -avd pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30
            4>Emulator pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 is running.
            4>Deploying to pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30 ...
            Build started.
            Project "Jeevitham.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
            Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
            Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
              PackageName: com.companyname.jeevitham
            Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
            MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
            Android Platform API level: 30
            TargetFrameworkVersion: v11.0
            Android NDK: 
            Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
            Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\
            Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\
            Application Java class: android.app.Application
            Project "Jeevitham.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):
            Done building project "Jeevitham.csproj".
            Project "Jeevitham.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
            Done building project "Jeevitham.csproj".
            Project "Jeevitham.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
            Done building project "Jeevitham.csproj".
            Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
            ...
            Skipping target "_CompileToDalvik" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
            Copying file from "z:\mobile\VSPodcast\Jeevitham new\Jeevitham\Jeevitham.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\bin\com.companyname.jeevitham.apk" to "z:\mobile\VSPodcast\Jeevitham new\Jeevitham\Jeevitham.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.jeevitham.apk".
```

Continued output log in the output Window:

```
            Creating "obj\Debug\110\android_debug_keystore.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\zipalign.exe -p 4 "z:\mobile\VSPodcast\Jeevitham new\Jeevitham\Jeevitham.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\bin\com.companyname.jeevitham.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.companyname.jeevitham-Signed.apk" 
            C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\Users\John Mangam\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 21 --max-sdk-version 30  "z:\mobile\VSPodcast\Jeevitham new\Jeevitham\Jeevitham.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.jeevitham-Signed.apk" 
            Signed android package 'bin\Debug\com.companyname.jeevitham-Signed.apk'
            Using cached value from RegisterTaskObject
            Found device: emulator-5554
            Creating "obj\Debug\110\upload.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
            Creating directory "obj\.cache\".
            Done building project "Jeevitham.Android.csproj".
            Build succeeded.
            4>Deployment was successful to pixel_2_r_11_0_-_api_30.
            ========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
            ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please enable `Use shared runtime` and `Use fast deployment`, please check the "Deploy" if selected as well in the configuration manager like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/ewLmGrd

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I enabled but it still doesn't work. I don't see the use shared runtime option. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/gRemjjY

Comment: You can create a new project, if you have a similar issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you for your suggestion, the issue is with the newly created project as well. I have updated the question with the log. Thank you.

Comment: Please check if you have enabled the hardware acceleration for emulator like this thread.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows And do you have Android device? if so, you can try to deploy it.